# Need code for iframe login to open new window after submit

Tags: wordpress, iframe, authentication

This is our current client login:https://www08.8f7.com/4DACTION/WebShowMenu
Clients access this by clicking the button on our home page.

As you can see it's not branded & has no information for those landing on this page. I'm trying to iframe this on a page on our site:
https://onesourcebackground.com/client-login/

I got it to work. However when you login, it stays on the same page within an iframe. I'd prefer that when someone clicks the submit/Log in button it will open the logged in dashboard in a new tab or window - no iframe. This way it's the full browser width and clients have the view they are used to having.

Our site is on a Wordpress platform (vers 4.4.2). Using Enfold Theme (vers. 3.5.1) and their Code Block element. I have Googled this quite a bit - including browsing SO. But the code given doesn't seem to work for my needs.

Is this possible to do? If so, could someone provide the code or script in it's entirety?

Here's what I currently have in the Enfold Code Block element:

```
<iframe src="https://www08.8f7.com/4DACTION/WebShowMenu" onload='javascript:(function(o){o.style.height=o.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight+"px";}(this));' style="height:200px;width:100%;border:none;overflow:hidden;"></iframe>
```

Enfold theme also has a Quick CSS box so if I need to add CSS to make this happen, please let me know.

Comment: I don't think this is possible.

Comment: Other options? I came across this code:

Comment: I came across this code: `<iframe src="https://www08.8f7.com/4DACTION/WebShowMenu" onload="this.width=screen.width;this.height=screen.height;">` But aside from the top navigation, it now knocks out all the other elements from the page. Prefer the elements stay until after login. Is there a modification to the code that would just push everything else down the page? Or could I create another page similar to this one that it could direct to after clicking the login? I know I've come across some posts about same domain, etc. Not sure since the link is not on the same domain, etc.?